# Is there a way to place forms on to one .cfm page and the call them out on different cfm pages using CFINCLUDE

Tags: coldfusion

Question I would like to create a single .cfm page containing multiple HTML Form templates and then call these templates onto different .cfm pages. This way I can go to one single .cfm page to make changes to the specific form. Similar to .cfc. Or should I use a .cfc to do this?

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance, Dave G.

Comment: Your hopes are not fulfilled.  It does not make sense.  At least not to me.

Comment: Using a monolithic file like that is pretty much contrary to any/all best practices out there. Why would you want do do that?? Not sure why there's a vote to close on this? The question is clear (if wrong-headed), and reasonable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Go modular, instead of following bad programming practice! Is there a reason for not having separate .cfm partials for each for your forms?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. It's just a bad way of managing ones code. Keep your files restricted to one purpose per file, where with forms: that'd be one form (or part of one form!) per file. You should be aiming for more smaller, purpose-focused files, not fewer monolithic ones.

That said, there's no *nice* way to do this with a CFM file (nor should there be, as that would encourage people to do it. Which would be poor form on the part of CFML). You could always follow one bad practice of putting your mark-up into CFC methods and having a method per form.

Or you could follow another bad practice and have a monolithic `switch` statement in a CFM file, the `case`es for which each contain one of your forms.

But simply don't. It's a rubbish, wrong-headed way of going about things.